# How to prevent image view loading while scrolling in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development. I want to check whether the image is loaded in the image view and if the image view is nil then load the image. I want to implement this in cell for row at index path so that I can increase the scrolling performance of the table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily Apple provides a sample that does just this, [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html). You can move IconDownloader into your project and then change your TableViewController implementation to look like that of RootViewController

Comment: How can i implement this i am showing many view with images in table

Comment: Each of your table view controllers in which you want to lazily load images should have code similar to RootViewController.